# iOS7 UILabel visual glitch

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I´m having trouble reproducing a visual glitch in a UITableViewController. Actually a SCTableViewController from the SensibleTableView Component.

So I´m constructing a static grouped TableView in -viewDidLoad:.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    SCTableViewSection *sec = [SCTableViewSection sectionWithHeaderTitle:@"hdas"];

    SCLabelCell *c1 = [SCLabelCell cellWithText:@"dsan"];
    [sec addCell:c1];

    [[self tableViewModel] addSection:sec];
}
```

And what I´m seeing is a weird thin grey border on the right edge of the label. (Marked with red triangle)

Where would I look to remove this bar? Why does it even appear?

I tried setting backgroundColor, layer borders, layer shadows, textShadow etc.

[image: iOS7 UILabel visual glitch]

Comment: Looks like the "Enter text here" cursor to me - it doesn't happen to be an UITextField instead of a Label?

Comment: There´s no UITextField anywhere in this view :-(

Comment: When you make the label wider, does the stripe move to the right?

Comment: Yes it does. It seems to be attached to the frame of the UILabel.

Comment: This is only an issue on the device. not in the simulator.

Comment: This happens for me as well, when I try to optimize blended layers by setting the background color on views in a UITableViewCell. Very annoying, and I've yet to find a satisfying solution.

Answer (score 6):

use UILabel.backgroundColor, set label's backgroundColor raise this problem.
you can fix this bug by set Layer's backgroundColor by UILabel.layer.backgroundColor.

"Setting background color as clear fixed for me." by Nuthinking. can fix this bug too. But in tableView this may be reduced performance a little.

Comment: This is the answer. Nice.

Answer (score 4):

Setting background color as clear fixed for me.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the view's OPAQUE property to YES fixed it for me.